# oracle trigger and json_value

Tags: sql, json, oracle, triggers

Hi I want to store some values from :new.payload via an trigger.

this works in sql-developer but not in a trigger...

```
select json_value('{"timestamp":"2019-05-09T14:00:00Z","value":0,"unit":"W/m²"}', '$.unit') from dual;
```

'{"timestamp":"2019-05-09T14:00:00Z","value":0,"unit":"W/m²"}' is my :new.payload

i tried also:

```
SELECT unit INTO v_unit
    FROM
        json_table(:new.payload, '$'
            columns (
                    timestamp VARCHAR2(80) path '$.timestamp',
                    value NUMBER path '$.value',
                    unit VARCHAR2(80) path '$.unit'
                    )
) jt;
```

i get the error ORA-00904: "DECL_OBJ#" ;/

(Error: ORA-00604: Recursive Error SQL-Level 1 ORA-00904: "DECL_OBJ #": invalid ID)

Comment: Please edit the question and show the entire error including call stack.  Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a wild guess, but try this:

1.Open SQL Developer Set the PLScope identifiers parameter (Tools > Preferences > Database > PL/SQL Compiler > PLScope identifiers) from All to None.

2. Close and open the SQL Developer

Comment: that's it? Really? okay ... why does that work now?

Comment: I looked for that error on the Oracle support site and found notes about it. It is an internal oracle error. You would need an oracle support account to get the details.

Comment: You can read the details here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vy3GRqUezdhRb-FENY8eurGvx6UIUZUb/view?usp=sharing